# Google+ Server Side Token Validation

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I am using Google+ Sign-in in my application. A user gets an access_token back and I want to pass that token to my server and verify it with google. What is confusing me is conflicting information in google's documentation regarding the security of this:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken

Says I can make an ajax call with the access_token to check if it is a valid token. This works fine for me, however,

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/client-to-server-flow

Says never to send the access_token as a parameter in an http request to my server.

So, is it safe to use `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between sending the access token in an HTTP request to **your** server and sending it to **Google**'s server.

When sending the access token to Google's tokeninfo endpoint for validation it's OK to send it as a query parameter, since it runs over HTTPs and Google is the issuer of the access token in the first place, so you're sending it to a known and controlled environment. Google assumes that Google knows what its doing.

But when sending the access token from client to **your** server (and you must make sure you use HTTPs anyhow) passing it as a query parameter is less secure since it may end up in logs and traffic analysis data on the server end. Examples of that are situations where there's a proxy in between client and server or you're using web hosting.

On top of that there are sophisticated attacks against OAuth 2.0 enabled systems that exploit the the fact that query parameters with tokens end up in `Location` and `Referer` headers. It is better to avoid the possibility of being exposed to any vulnerability like that. For a nice impression of those attacks, see http://www.oauthsecurity.com/ especially the section on open redirects.

Answer (score 0):

I think the docs are saying to not use the access token as a GET parameter to your web app because most web servers will log the URLs accessed in an unprotected location unless it's specifically configured to not do it. So if you did an AJAX request to your backend server, the user's access token would be exposed in the web server logs.

Using the `tokeninfo` endpoint should be fine because Google does the logging and will handle the security of the logs. HTTPS protects the request URL and the message, so there are no special concerns using the access token as a GET parameter.